# Replace Episerver Commerce Editor (TinyMCE)

Tags: tinymce, episerver, commerce

Is there anybody who knows how can I replace TinyMCE with the default editor on Episerver Commerce SP2?

Comment: Yeah, I believe they even ship another editor with the standard installation. And if that don't do you can create your own field type and connect a custom control that use any custom editor you want.

Comment: Oh, and change your username. Noone will answer your question with a nick like that.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Do you have any example of a Tiny MCE control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy tiny_mce folder to eCommerceFramework\5.2\EPiServerCommerceManager\Shared\Apps\Core\Controls\Editors\
2. Copy TinyMCEEditor.dll to the \bin folder in your Commerce Manager site.
3. In the Commerce Manager site folder open appSettings.config. Change the 2 keys “HtmlEditorControl” and “AdminHtmlEditorControl” to the new editor path.
4. Create folder name “UserFiles” in the root folder of Commerce Manager site.
5. Done, enter Commerce Manager and test the editor.
6. Use the following Control :

   ```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditorControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="TinyMCEEditor.EditorControl" %>
   ```

   tinyMCE.init({ 
   // General options 
   mode: "textareas", 
   theme: "advanced", 
   plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist",
   file_browser_callback : "filebrowser",
   setup: function(ed) { 
   ed.onKeyPress.add( 
   function(ed, evt) { 
   } 
   ); 
   }, 
   // Theme options 
   theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,charmap,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
   theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,cleanup,code,|,preview", 
   theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols", 
   theme_advanced_buttons4: "", 
   theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top", 
   theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left", 
   theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom", 
   theme_advanced_resizing: true, 
   // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS) 
   content_css: "css/content.css", 
   // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs 
   template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js", 
   external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js", 
   external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js", 
   media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js", 
   // Style formats 
   style_formats: [ 
   { title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b' }, 
   { title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} }, 
   { title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: { color: '#ff0000'} }, 
   { title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1' }, 
   { title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2' }, 
   { title: 'Table styles' }, 
   { title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1' } 
   ], 
   // Replace values for the template plugin 
   template_replace_values: { 
   username: "Some User", 
   staffid: "991234" 
   }
   });

   function filebrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {

   ```
   fileBrowserURL = "../FileManager/Default.aspx?sessionid=<%= Session.SessionID.ToString() %>";


       tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
           title: "Ajax File Manager",
           url: fileBrowserURL,
           width: 950,
           height: 650,
           inline: 0,
           maximizable: 1,
           close_previous: 0
           }, {
           window: win,
           input: field_name,
           sessionid: '<%= Session.SessionID.ToString() %>'
           }
       );
   }
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
       $(".ajax__htmleditor_editor_toptoolbar").each(function (index) {
           $(this).html($(this).html() + "<img onclick=showImgManager('" + index + "') src='../FileManager/icons/img-add-32.png' class='ajax__htmleditor_toolbar_button' /><img onclick=showFileManager('" + index + "') src='../FileManager/icons/Files-add-32.png' class='ajax__htmleditor_toolbar_button' /><div style='display:none;float:left;width:100%;padding-top:5px;' id='divImgManager" + index + "'></div>");
       });
       function openFileManager(index) {
           window.open("../FileManager/Default.aspx?sessionid=<%= Session.SessionID %>&input=" + index, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 650, width = 950, resizable = 0")
       }

   </script>
   <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 40%" 
   runat="server"></textarea>
   ```